# Border and values not matching in PDF

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

This happens when I use display: inline-block to wrap a table. The table itself is in the correct position *(shown as pink)*, but the border is shifted down.

[image: display:inline-block result]

Here is the code I used. The three table has the same code, so I removed the other two. And I removed the codes used to setup `dompdf`

```
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <table class="table-bordered" style="background-color: pink;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-left p-2">
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        Some Name
                    </p>
                    <p class="mb-0">
                        Some Date
                    </p>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left p-1">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="p-1">
                    VALUE
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left p-1">
                    DATA
                </td>
                <td class="p-1">
                    VALUE
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I use display: inline-table instead, this happens:

[image: display:inline-table result]

The table is alright, but it is not in line anymore.

And this is when I used `float:left`:

[image: float:left result]

In line, but the border seems to moved to the leftmost side as well

I'm doing this because I can't use the grid system of Bootstrap 4 *(uses flex)*, and I need small `divs` that are inline.

Any idea on possible solutions for this problem or the cause? I want it to be in line and borders properly placed. All of these are showing me the expected result when viewed in the browser, but not in the PDF.

Comment: Hi,Can you share the css too?

Comment: @Amal The classes I used is from Bootstrap 4

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/0rvjuwh5/ How about adding three table inside td's.It work for me here in my html to pdf converter.

Comment: I'll try rendering it to PDF

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

You can add three table's inside each `td` of another table.

```html
<table style="table-layout:fixed;margin:0 auto;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="vertical-align:top;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
     <table class="table-bordered" style="background-color: pink;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-left p-2" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Name
         </p>
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Date
         </p>
        </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td style="vertical-align:top;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
     <table class="table-bordered" style="background-color: pink;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-left p-2" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Name
         </p>
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Date
         </p>
        </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
   <td style="vertical-align:top;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
     <table class="table-bordered" style="background-color: pink;table-layout: fixed;border-collapse: collapse;">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-left p-2" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Name
         </p>
         <p class="mb-0">
          Some Date
         </p>
        </th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="text-left p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         DATA
        </td>
        <td class="p-1" style="border: 1px solid #000;">
         VALUE
        </td>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Although it is okay in the browser, in the PDF it is not. I had to alter it a bit to make it work.

Comment: Ok.So you fixed your issue?

Comment: Not really, I realized that using a table as a parent is not good because the child tables are dynamic, and the parent table will just go longer and longer in width, surpassing the width of the paper